# I can't make post. Creates a new local post associated with the specified location. google my business API

Tags: google-my-business-api

I'am trying to make post to google map location by
[accounts.locations.localPosts.create](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.localPosts/create)

Done steps

- Set up credentials(https://console.cloud.google.com/ configuration )
- Did successful steps OAuth 2.0 Playground [Google developers](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground)
- Step 1. Select & authorize APIs with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage`(successful)
- Step 2. Exchange authorization code for tokens (successful)
- Step 3. Configure request to API `POST https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/Ch3JWaJf0g43zUARwtG3wplmUM/localPosts`(404 Not Found)

[image]

`POST https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/My location/localPosts` - (404 Not Found also if I use name of location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resource path does not match the expected pattern - it should be `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{{LOCATION_GROUP_ID}}/locations/{{LOCATION_ID}}/localPosts`

Comment: Thanks. I have Project number, Project ID, location place_id... But don't have LOCATION_GROUP_ID. Can your say? Is  it some account ID I need to get with other request? I did https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v1/accounts, but still have Request a higher quota limit. I have 0. I am wait 1-2 weeks to get permission for a larger quota

Comment: You need to make a GET accounts request to find out the location group id. Same goes for GET locations. The Google Maps place id is not the same as the GBP location id. Without quotas for the GMB API, GBP Account API and GBP Location API, there's not much point continuing with this.